# Javascript validation form return false not working on Safari Browser in IOS

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, safari

I have written condition on checking date and if lead time is less than 4 hours, show error message and do not allow further action to happen. In Android mobile and website it is working fine.

In Iphone safari browser it doesnt show my message and doesnot return false and continues to perform next action. What is wrong with my code

```js
function validate_form() {
  var mytext = "";
  document.getElementById("mytext").innerHTML = "";

  if ($("#pickup_time").val().trim() !== "") {
    var inputDate = new Date($("#pickup_time").val().trim());
    var todaysDate = new Date();

    if (inputDate.setHours(0, 0, 0, 0) == todaysDate.setHours(0, 0, 0, 0)) {
      var pickup_time = $("#pickup_time").val().trim();
      var pickup_min = pickup_time.substr(pickup_time.length - 2);
      pickup_time = pickup_time.substr(pickup_time.length - 5);
      pickup_time = pickup_time.substr(0, 2);
      var date = new Date();
      var hours = date.getHours() < 10 ? "0" + date.getHours() : date.getHours();
      var minutes = date.getMinutes() < 10 ? "0" + date.getMinutes() : date.getMinutes();
      hours = hours + 4;

      if (pickup_time === hours) {
        if (pickup_min >= minutes) {
          return true;
        } else {
          document.getElementById("mytext").innerHTML = "Minimum lead time required is 4Hrs to schedule a Car!";
          return false;
        }
      } else if (pickup_time < hours) {
        document.getElementById("mytext").innerHTML = "Minimum lead time required is 4Hrs to schedule a Car!";
        return false;
      }
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form action="success.html" method="post" class="chafviews" id="booknow" onsubmit="return validate_form(event)">
  <div class="pickCont">
    <input type="text" class="textField pick_datepicker" value="" name="pickup_time" id="pickup_time" placeholder="Select start date" />
    <div class="fieldLable">Pickup Date and Time</div>
  </div>
  <div class="pickCont">
    <input type="text" class="textField drop_datepicker" value="" name="dropoff_time" id="dropoff_time" placeholder="Select end date" />
    <div class="fieldLable">Drop-off Date and Time</div>
  </div>
  <p id="mytext" style="color: red; margin-top: 50px; font-size: 13px;"></p>
  <input type="submit" class="selfBook" value="Proceed" />
</form>
```

Comment: There seems to be some logic flow issues in your validation. Exactly what is the condition(s) to be validated? I'm sure there's a simpler and more efficient way to achieve it

Comment: yes, i know logic flow doesnt seem upto the mark. but it works perfectly fine in android mobile and websites. Condition is I cannot book a car without lead time of 4 hours. i.e. minimum 4 hrs gap is required from current time to book a car

Comment: Need a little more information . . . what format is the value that you are expecting from "#pickup_time" in?

Comment: Also, you also have some value type and comparison issues . . . specifically, `pickup_time` and `pickup_min` will always be strings, but you are comparing them to `hours` and `minutes`, which may either be a string or an integer, depending on the current time.  Particularly in the case of the hours check (which uses a `===`), this will always fail, when `hours` is an integer, so, in theory, the difference in behavior could actually be because of testing with different pickup time values.

Comment: the format i am getting from #pickup_time is Fri May 17 2019 10:40:00 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time).   And comparsion i have tried with  === and == as well. And also parsed both to same format and checked eg:pickup_min  and minutes , In IOS still not solved

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17423557/why-does-mobile-safari-seem-to-give-different-javascript-date-results-from-des